# Isotope + Wordpress layout mode

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I'm having a hard time setting up the isotope layout mode in wordpress. What I'm trying to do is create a 2 column grid as seen in [this example](http://www.radicalessex.uk/essex-architecture-weekend). So far I managed to get isotope working with filtering categories. The only thing I'm stuggling with is to get the responsive images in a 2 column grid as seen in the example. This is what I have so far: [live example](http://goedgevonden.net/elien)

index.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container-moving">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=50' ); //Check the WP_Query docs to see how you can limit which posts to display ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div id="isotope-list">
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );  //Get the terms for this particular item
    $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
            $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
        }
    ?> 
    <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item"> <?php // 'item' is used as an identifier (see Setp 5, line 6) ?>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                      the_post_thumbnail();
                } ?><br>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div> <!-- end item -->
    <?php endwhile;  ?>
    </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
<?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

isotope.js

```
jQuery(function ($) {

 var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
 $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
 itemSelector : '.item', 
   layoutMode : 'masonry', });

 //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
 var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
 $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

 $optionLinks.click(function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 // don't proceed if already selected
 if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
   return false;
 }
 var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
 $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
 $this.addClass('selected');

 //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
 var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
 $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

 return false;
 });

});
```

isotope.css

```
/* Start: Recommended Isotope styles */

/**** Isotope Filtering ****/

.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;

}

.item {

}


.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
          transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
     -moz-transition-property: height, width;
      -ms-transition-property: height, width;
       -o-transition-property: height, width;
          transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
     -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
      -ms-transition-property:     -ms-transform, opacity;
       -o-transition-property:      -o-transform, opacity;
          transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}

/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/

.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
      -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
       -o-transition-duration: 0s;
          transition-duration: 0s;
}
/* End: Recommended Isotope styles */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do would be to create an image size for wordpress to force the images to be the have the same height and width properties.

```
add_image_size( 'masonryLayout', 300, 300, true );
```

Note that you will need to reupload your images in order to create the new image sizes in the media library.

Then you would want to force the .item div to be 50% width. The img tag would need to fill the .item container.

```
.item{
     width: 50%
}
.item img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend creating the layout and getting it perfect in static HTML before trying to incorporate into Wordpress. It's much easier that way.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, however now when I load my page in firefox or safari I see my images are stacked upon eachother. When I filter them or click on All images it's gone

Comment: I've seen this behavior before. It's a bug that happens when the isotope fires before the images are fully downloaded. You can fix this issue by using the images loaded plugin. 

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: Ok thanks for the documentation! I'm going to check it out later